# mediaItems endpoint just returns 2 items, have more than 10K in my libraray

Tags: google-photos

So i was creating a script to see what items have been uploaded to google photos and what items have not.

Yesterday this worked fine, fetching more than 8K items using the same script, only now its just returning 2 pictures, both taken yesterday. When investigating further using postman I'm also getting just 2 results back of yesterday. Now I've removed those images (since they where screenshots and I don't want to keep them) now the list is empty

This is the CURL

```bash
curl --location --request GET 'https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer xxx'
```

This is the result

```json
{
    "nextPageToken": "xxxxxx"
}
```

My library contains more than 10K photos so I'm a bit confused. Is there some counter somewhere stating that this is the last page? It seems like it, since the next page using the nextpagetoken is empty.

Hope if someone has the answer for me. Thanks!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: And how looks your script?

Comment: Ive edited my answer to remove the img, and insert the curl command. Since the call to the API is failing, I think we can leave my script out of it.